# Trie vs B+ tree

Tags: algorithm

How does Trie and B+ tree compare for indexing lexicographically sorted strings [on the order some billions]? 
It should support range queries as well.

From perf. as well as implementation complexity point of view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would say it depends on what you mean by *Range*.

If your range is expressed as *All words beginning by*, then a `Trie` is the right choice I'd say. On the other hand, `Trie` are not meant for requests like *All words between XX and ZZ*.

Note that the branching factor of the `B+ Tree` affects its performance (the number of intermediary nodes). If `h` is the height of the tree, then n<sub>max</sub> ~~ b<sup>h</sup>. Therefore h ~~ log(n<sub>max</sub>) / log(b).

With `n = 1 000 000 000` and `b = 100`, we have `h ~~ 5`. Therefore it means only 5 pointer dereferencing for going from the root to the leaf. It's more cache-friendly than a `Trie`.

Finally, `B+ Tree` is admittedly more difficult to implement than a `Trie`: it's more on a `Red-Black Tree` level of complexity.

Comment: If you are smart about your Trie implementation than "all words between xx and zz" isn't that difficult.  If you are storing the edges in lexicographical order then the strings are in lexicographical order as well.

Comment: It's a bit more difficult though to exploit the range. In a `B+ Tree` a range can be defined by two pointers (begin/end) and you can iterate through them like in a deque. In a `Trie` you have to implement iteration (from a random pointer to another) in order to be able to do the same, it's less natural, though of course not infeasible and I am afraid less efficient. Or you can just copy the range in another structure, but that could be costly.

Comment: down-voted it by mistake, was supposed to upvote it. I am not able to change it back now :(

Comment: @Suraj: I have edited the post (added a space) so you should normally be able to change your vote :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I would note on the naturalness of having a companion structure to the trie in the very common case of structuring data as mapped to URLs, namespaces or JSON-like-objects. When you have obvious branch delimiters such as `/` or `.`in the key and  `""`, `''`, `{}` or `[]` in the object, you are basically using the trie to preresolve a pointer-to-key mapping so that dereferencing of any scope is based on the depth of the *logical* scope being accessed. for semantic keyspaces this is pretty useful. though there are variations of the trie that are better at this behavior too

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your actual task:

- If you want to get the **whole subtree**, a **B+Tree** is your best choice because it is space efficient.
- But if you want to get the **first `N` children** from a substree, then a **Trie** is the best choice because you simply visit less nodes than in a B+ Tree scenario.
- The most popular task which is well-handled by a **Trie** is a **word prefix completion**.

Comment: Some variations of tries I am using are not only more space-efficient than BTrees, but also faster for most queries (direct access, word completion, range query).

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has some algorithmic complexity facts: 
[B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree#Characteristics) (section Characteristics), [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (unfortunately spread all over the article). Hope that helps.

Comment: Please include the relevant facts in the answer. Simply linking to Wikipedia isn't useful.